# Inaccurate length of string when using 'strlen'

Tags: arrays, c, string, character, strlen

I am getting inaccurate string length when printing the length of a string using the `strlen` function.

I am getting the output for string `a` as 5 (which is correct), but when I am printing the length of string `b`, the output comes out to be 10 **(which should be 5)**.

Here is the code snippet:

```
char a[] = "Yolow";
char b[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
printf("len = %d\n", strlen(a));
printf("len = %d", strlen(b));
```

Comment: The perennial question: "How long is a (piece of) string?" :-)

Comment: From the edit: string `b` has no nul terminator. Just 5 elements. The nul terminator is only supplied automatically for string `a` where the value is itself a string (and only if there is room). Applying `strlen(b)` is *undefined behaviour* although in this case it would appear that `b` is before `a` in memory, and `strlen` overruns `b` until the end of `a`.

Comment: `char a[] = "Yolow";` is equivalent to `char a[] = {'Y', 'o', 'l', 'o', 'w', 0};`. That should answer the question. IOW: `b` is just an array of 5 characters, there is no terminating null character.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Ok string b doesn't has a null character to terminate the string. But whenever I run the program the length of string b comes out to be 10(why so). Also if I increase the length of string **a** it also increases the length of string b by the same unit.

Comment: @ManasSaha explained in my comment.

Comment: @Weather Vane
 How can you determine that b is before a? And what do you mean by strlen overruns b until the end of a.

Comment: It was a guess, based on the reported behaviour, and the posted code. Because `b` has no terminator, `strlen` function just keeps on going until it found another one in memory. If you `printf("%s\n", b);` again there is no string terminator and if get `HelloYolow` you should be able to verify that is what happened. It's undefined behaviour though, to pass an array with no terminator to a function that expects a proper C string, and something else might happen.

Comment: @ManasSaha what you see here is _undefined behavior_ (google that term). On your platform it happens to be 10 each time (probably because the two arrays are adjacent in memory, see other comments), but on an other platform the outcome could be different or your program might crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the original:

```
char b[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
```

and here's a fix that turns an array of characters into a (null terminated) "string":

```
char b[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' }; // add ASCII 'NUL' to the array
```

or, alternatively:

```
char b[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o',   0 }; // add zero to the array
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, strings end at 0 byte. It is automatically there when you have string literal using `""`, and when you use string functions to modify strings (exception: `strncpy`).

But your `b` does not have this 0 byte, so it is not actually a string, it is just a char array. You can't use string functions like `strlen` with it!

To put the 0 there, you can do this:

```
char b[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

Note: Using `'\0'` instead of just `0` is just cosmetic, making it explicit this is 0 byte value character. Using just `0` is equal syntax, if you prefer that.

Comment: Ok, string b doesn't has a null character to terminate the string. But whenever I run the program the length of string b comes out to be 10(why so every time). Also if I increase the length of string a it also increases the length of string b by the same unit.

Comment: @ManasSaha I'll expand the answer later, but it is, because `strlen` will cause a buffer overrun, reading past the end of the memory block. This is *Undefined Behavior*, so `strlen` may crash, return a random number, or do something else. In practice, it's very likely there is a zero byte quite soon, so `strlen` thinks that's the end of string and returns a length which is too big. But, *Undefined Behavior*, no guarantees of any kind.